# Need python class decorator of parent to run when class is inherited

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working with an example from py.test(using xdist) that uses the unittest library.

I have a class:

```
def on_platforms(platforms):
    def decorator(base_class):
        module = sys.modules[base_class.__module__].__dict__
        for i, platform in enumerate(platforms):
            d = dict(base_class.__dict__)
            d['desired_capabilities'] = platform
            name = "%s_%s" % (base_class.__name__, i + 1)
        module[name] = new.classobj(name, (base_class,), d)
return decorator

@on_platforms(browsers)
class BaseTest:
    def setUp(self):
        pass
```

This contains common code that I need to run in all the test classes I will create.  In the files that contain actual tests to run I have:

```
from BaseTest.py import BaseTest
class FirstTest(BaseTest):
    def test_to_run(self):
        pass
```

Then I have a single main file which will import all the test classes and run them all when the main.py file is executed.

main.py:
    import unittest
    from FirstTest.py import FirstTest

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Finally, I attempt to execute with:

```
py.test main.py -n3 --boxed
```

But what happens is it executes main.py succesfully but no tests are run.  Why aren't the test being run?  Thanks.

Comment: Are the `return` statements in your decorator correct? They look to be at least indented wrong, and the inner one is probably supposed to be `return base_class` instead of `return module`. Also, which version of Python are you using (2 or 3)?

Comment: Having a `return` statement at top level is going to be a `SyntaxError`, so I can't imagine you've actually fixed it properly. Also, returning `module` will result in `BaseTest` being a dictionary, rather than a type, so you won't be able to subclass it in other code at all.

Comment: You're right, I still didn't get the edit right.

But your comment does explain some behavior I didn't understand.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a metaclass, rather than a decorator to create the extra versions of your `BaseClass`. The metaclass will be called to create any subclasses that are created by later code (while the decorator will not). This means you'll get copies of the subclasses automatically.

```
import sys

browsers=['x','y','z']

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        cls = type.__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)
        mod_dct = sys.modules[cls.__module__].__dict__
        if 'desired_capabilities' not in dct:
            for i, platform in enumerate(cls.platforms):
                sub_name = "%s_%s" % (name, i + 1)
                sub_cls = meta(sub_name, (cls,), {'desired_capabilities': platform})
                mod_dct[sub_name] = sub_cls
        return cls

class BaseTest(metaclass=Meta):  # metaclass code will create BaseTest_1, BaseTest_2, ...
    platforms = browsers
    def setUp(self):
        pass

class SubTest(BaseTest):  # metaclass code will create SubTest_1, SubTest_2, ...
    pass
```

This uses Python 3 syntax for the metaclass. If you're using Python 2, inherit from `object` and use the `__metaclass__` class variable instead:

```
class BaseTest(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    # ...
```

The `platforms` class attribute will be inherited by subclasses of `BaseTest` (though they can override it with their own list) and the metaclass will create the extra subclasses for them. The `if 'desired_capabilities' not in dct` test is needed to make sure the platform-specific subclasses the metaclass creates for you do not recursively get their own subclasses.